# Am I using the State Pattern correctly?

Tags: swift, state-machine

I'm learning the State Pattern (Finite State Machine) 
In the sample project that I built the only way that I figured out to update the UI is to pass a reference of the presenting view to the state machine, and then update the UI from the state I'm working. Am I doing it wrong?

*Here's my State Machine*

```
class CapturePhotoStateMachine {
    var noPictureTakenState: NoPictureTakenState?
    var pictureTakenState: PictureTakenState?
    var initialState: InitialState?
    var vc: SignupAvatarView?

    var capturePhotoState: CapturePhotoState?

    init(viewController: SignupAvatarView) {
        noPictureTakenState = NoPictureTakenState(stateMachine: self)
        pictureTakenState = PictureTakenState(stateMachine: self)
        initialState = InitialState(stateMachine: self)
        vc = viewController
        capturePhotoState = initialState
    }

    func setCapturePhotoState(newState: CapturePhotoState) {
        self.capturePhotoState = newState
    }

    func takePicture() {
        self.capturePhotoState?.takePicture()
    }

    func savePicture(image: UIImage) {
        self.capturePhotoState?.savePicture(image: image)
    }


    func retakePicture() {
        self.capturePhotoState?.retakePicture()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.capturePhotoState?.setup()
    }
}
```

*Here's my protocol*

```
protocol CapturePhotoState {
    func takePicture()
    func savePicture(image: UIImage)
    func retakePicture()
    func setup()
}
```

*Here's a subclass of state*

```
class NoPictureTakenState: CapturePhotoState {

    var stateMachine: CapturePhotoStateMachine?

    init(stateMachine: CapturePhotoStateMachine) {
        self.stateMachine = stateMachine
    }

    func takePicture() {
        stateMachine!.vc?.previewView.isHidden = true
        stateMachine!.vc?.capturedImage.isHidden = false
        stateMachine!.vc?.saveButton.isHidden = false
        stateMachine!.vc?.retakePhoto.isHidden = false
        stateMachine?.setCapturePhotoState(newState: (stateMachine?.pictureTakenState)!)
    }

    func savePicture(image: UIImage) {
    }

    func retakePicture() {}

    func setup() {}
}
```

Comment: It's not a job of a state in a state machine to do stuff to do the view. When a given state is entered, subscribed observers should be notified, and react accordingly. One such subscription might be by the UI layer, which will respond by doing this UI work.

Comment: @Alexander The question is deeply flawed (not enough info) but it doesn't look like he's talking to the UI — he's just being a state talking to the owner state machine, which then does the work (and we don't know how it does that). Without knowing what this state machine is, and how this particular state comes into existence and is held (by the state machine? if so, he's got a retain cycle), it's really hard to do anything but guess.

Comment: @Alexander Another question I would have is why exactly the state machine should not be allowed to talk directly to the interface. This is a singleton being used as a helper inside a view controller (I assume). Thus in a sense all we are doing is isolating a certain part of the view controller's thought process into a singleton object. I think of this as a piece of the view controller's brain (e.g. a lobe of the brain). So since the state machine _is_ part of the view controller, why shouldn't it do view controller work? Isn't that just what it is for?

Comment: I have added the other parts of the fsm to give more context.

Comment: Well to start with the first three lines look very wrong. The state machine should not have three variables, one for each state. It should have _one_ variable: the current state. Otherwise this is not a state machine at all.

Comment: I'd suggest to use enums to define your states, you can see an example here: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/modelling-state-in-swift

Comment: I agree with @almas, that's a very nicely written little discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to your state machine's purpose seems to be that you have interface objects you want to enable or disable depending on the state. That enablement / disablement should be the job of the view controller. The state itself is simply the basis on which questions can be answered such as "What is the current situation" and "What should happen next".

Here's a short simple state machine example that illustrates. It is deliberately trivial. We have just two buttons, and just two states; in each state, exactly one button should be enabled. The states are represented by cases of an enum, and we use a setter observer on that enum to respond whenever the state changes. The enum encapsulates the logic of how many states there are and what the next state is, while the view controller mediates between state change and interface change:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var takePictureButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var deletePictureButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pictureImageView: UIImageView! // not used in the example

    @IBAction func doTakePicture(_ sender: Any) {
        // do stuff
        doNextState()
    }

    @IBAction func doDeletePicture(_ sender: Any) {
        // do stuff
        doNextState()
    }

    enum State {
        case pictureNotTaken
        case pictureTaken
        var nextState : State {
            switch self {
            case .pictureNotTaken:
                return .pictureTaken
            case .pictureTaken:
                return .pictureNotTaken
            }
        }
    }
    var state : State = .pictureNotTaken {
        didSet {
            updateInterface()
        }
    }
    func doNextState() {
        self.state = self.state.nextState // triggers the setter observer
    }
    func updateInterface() {
        switch state {
        case .pictureNotTaken:
            takePictureButton.isEnabled = true
            deletePictureButton.isEnabled = false
        case .pictureTaken:
            takePictureButton.isEnabled = false
            deletePictureButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

Probably what you want is some expansion of that pattern.

> the only way that I figured out to update the UI is to pass a reference of the presenting view to the state machine

That is what the above pattern does *not* do. The setter observer solves that problem for us.

---

Now, you might object that the `switch` statement in `updateInterface` is doing the wrong kind of work. It locates the knowledge of how the interface reflects the state entirely in the view controller. Your impulse is to say that surely that knowledge is part of the *state* (and that's why you constructed your code the way you did).

My reply would be: well, yes and no. I do sometimes feel that way, and the way I solve the problem is to endow the state machine with properties expressing all the questions the view controller might have about what the current state *means* as regards the interface. That way, the *knowledge* is moved to the state, but the *interface* is still governed, correctly, by the view controller.

So, for example, we might add these two properties to our State enum:

```
enum State {
    // ... everything else is as before ...
    var userCanTakePicture : Bool { return self == .pictureNotTaken }
    var userCanDeletePicture : Bool { return self == .pictureTaken }
}
```

So, now, our `updateInterface` doesn't need any special knowledge about what each state means; it merely asks the state what the *interface* should be, which is simpler and gives perhaps a more satisfying separation of powers:

```
func updateInterface() {
    self.takePictureButton.isEnabled = state.userCanTakePicture
    self.deletePictureButton.isEnabled = state.userCanDeletePicture
}
```